# Can not run imported maven project on STS

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I imported my maven project into STS on another PC and it's not working now. What I have done as below
1. configure tomcat in STS
2. import maven->existing project
3. select correct one in project property->Targeted Runtimes.

Right click on project and select Run As -> Run on server, Tomcat starts up correctly but browser says HTTP 404, The requested resource is not available.

I can see there is red cross on left bottom of project which indicates there is error, however when I expend project, there is no further indication where is the error. I guess there is configure missing/wrong, but I do not know which one. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At STS you can look at the part called "Markers" (near of the console log tab) where you find some error messages of your Project. Share these errors if you find some. Else try to share more information to your question.

Comment: That really helps, it's Dynamic Web Module version mismatch.